# Is it possible to get the height/width of an image that's not in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, image-processing

Is it possible to get the height and width of an image in the file system using JavaScript (i.e. an image that is not part of the DOM)? Or would I have to use JavaScript to inject the image into the DOM and grab the dimensions that way?

I ask because I'm writing a JavaScript method to render a UI component on the fly generated by Raphaël, which takes three image paths as part of the method parameters. These are then used to render the aforementioned UI component, and I need the dimensions of the images for positioning purposes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think as long as the image has loaded you can grab the width and height - you shouldn't have to inject it into the DOM though. For example:

```
var tmp = new Image();
tmp.onload = function() {
    console.log(tmp.width + ' x ' + tmp.height);
}
tmp.src = 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=4';
```

Comment: I get the width and height in console.log, but when I try to JSON.stringify() it, it doesn't print out. The object looks perfect in console, but I can't retrieve it

Answer (score 4):

You cannot necessarily get to "the file system", but you can do this:

```
v = new Image();
v.onload = function() {
  alert("size: " + String(v.width) + 'x' + String(v.height));
};
v.src = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/96269f5a69115aa0e461b6334292d651?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG";
```

Would you count that as "adding to the DOM"?

Answer (score 1):

You can download image with code:

```
var img=new Image(),imgWidth,imgHeight;
img.onerror=img.onload=function(ev) {
  ev=ev||event;
  if(ev.type==="error") {
    imgWidth=imgHeight=-1; // error loading image resourse
  }
  else {
    imgWidth=this.width; // orimgWidth=img.width
    imgHeight=this.height; // imgHeight=img.height
  }
}
img.src="url_to_image_file";
```

Answer (score -5):

Is it possible to get the height and width of an image in the file system using JavaScript (i.e. an image that is not part of the DOM)?

- No

Or would I have to use JavaScript to inject the image into the DOM and grab the dimensions that way?

- Yes

Comment: Yikes, that's just not true.  See all the other answers for details.

Comment: I think what I specifically said (accessing the file system) is not possible, but I should have said URL.